# node express handling POST and GET as a single request

Tags: node.js

I would like to handle both POST and GET requests as a single request, such that all of my routings and subsequent functions only need to process a single request, rather than duplicating everything once for GET and again for POST.

So I figure the simplest way of doing this is to convert a POST to a GET early on using middleware, is there any problem with this ?

```
if(req.method=='POST'){
  req.method = 'GET';
  req.query = req.body;
  delete(req.body);
}
```

Comment: Are you using express as you're middle ware or just the native node.js libraries?

Comment: Thanks @Mike, using express (mentioned in the title)

Comment: Well, there is one major issue here.  A GET request must not have side effects - that is, you mustn't use it for things like, say, adding or removing an item from a user's shopping cart, or deleting a resource, etc.  The reason is that browsers are permitted to prefetch URLs, web spiders may crawl your site, etc. and you would never want to change state based on that.  Any handler that does change any state should never respond to a GET request.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the same handler function for the both requests i.e

```
app.get('/', handlerFunction);
app.post('/', handlerFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have `express` respond to all POST requests as 302 redirects to the same URL (these are always GET requests).

Here's some sample code:

```
// Redirect all post requests
app.post('^*$', function(req, res) {

      // Now just issue the same request again, this time as a GET
      res.redirect(302, req.url);

    });
});
```

Side note: this will work but I wouldn't recommend this as a long term solution. If you decide you do need to handle POST requests differently from GET requests and the maintainability will become a pain. In the long run, you're better off having a clear definition for how to handle POST and GET requests rather than treating them the same.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended approach is to have the same handler function for both in this case. for eg.

```
app.get('/path', handler);
app.post('/path', handler);
```